# how prevent yii2 to execute select query when ever call Yii::$app->user->id

Tags: php, optimization, yii, yii2

When ever I use

```
Yii::$app->user->id
```

or

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest
```

Yii2  execute `SELECT * FROM`user`WHERE`id`='4'` .

How can I prevent this repetitive query in order to optimize my web app? 
Caching or defining global session variable and something like that.

Comment: Extend web user class and rewrite methods to take already existing object instead of load it from database.

Comment: This is totally wrong. Could you please show us the above code in Yii2's official source?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour Just call Yii::$app->user->id in a loop for 5 time and track queries in your DB management.It will execute 5 SELECT query in your DB.

Comment: @farhad2161 Nothing like that happens, This depends on how you created your user identity.

Comment: @farhad2161 Consider an example that I am working with a web service in order to authentication. So, running this query is funny

Comment: @AliMasudianPour I implemented IdentityInterface in my User model and when I call Yii::$app->user->id it cause to call findIdentity method and in this method I have "return static::findOne(['id' => $id]);". So this cause a SELECT query every time executed.How you implement this method to prevent repetitive query.

Comment: @farhad2161 You probably followed Yii2's basic application demo. Take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html specially at `getIdentity()` and `$enableSession`

Answer (score 0):

Enable one of the [supported cache storages](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html#supported-cache-storage) and replace the code `return static::findOne(['id' => $id]);` you mentioned in your comment with

```
$db = self::getDb();
return static::getDb()->cache(function ($db) use ($id) {
    return static::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one();
});
```

For more details, see
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-data.html